# How do I delete an old company page/profile?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-talent, companies-page

Occasionally I'll receive an email from stackoverflow regarding scheduled maintenance for Company Pages.

> Planned maintenance impacting Stack Overflow Company Pages scheduled for 2023-03-01

It goes to my personal email address but I have no idea which company it's for. I've tried to reset my password at https://talent.stackoverflow.com/users/resetpassword which sends me the email, but when I try to set a new one I receive a validation error:

> This account does not have a password associated with it to reset

So I logged in using Google OAuth, and it says "Subscription Expired". I can't find anywhere that will allow me to delete the profile.

I can't figure out how to a response via the "contact us" popup, as it seems to be just a giant FAQ with no way to actually contact someone.

I'd really like to stop receiving mail for a company I likely haven't worked at for 10 years or so.

Comment: "I can't figure out how to a response via the "contact us" popup, as it seems to be just a giant FAQ with no way to actually contact someone." – Are you talking about [this Contact Us page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), or something else? (I'm not personally sure if there's a particular email or contact link for help with Talent-related issues specifically, but if not, I figure the support folks can direct your request to the right team or point you in the right direction.)

Comment: The talent page has its own contact us link that opens a popup with "Home" "Messages" "Help" within which has a bunch of links to how-to articles.

Comment: After poking around a bit, I think I've figured out what you're looking at (though I don't have a Talent account, so I can't verify it myself)... I'm guessing [this Help Center for Talent](https://intercom.help/stackoverflowtalent/en/) is the FAQ you're talking about?

Comment: [This guide to resetting your password](https://intercom.help/stackoverflowtalent/en/articles/1692894-how-to-reset-your-stack-overflow-talent-password) seems to be relevant; it says: "If you continue to have issues, please contact support at our [help portal](https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new)." The linked page lets you submit a support ticket (click "Stack Overflow Talent" as the product you need help with).